# jQuery hover fadeIn fadeOut problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just got back to html, javascript and jquery and i'm a bit rusty. I've mostly been doing objective-c for a while and getting back to jquery is a little difficult. I'm trying to use the jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut bit but its not working for some reason... Here's the html and js I've been working on :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js">
function showImg(2img) {
          $(2img).fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
      });
}

function hideImg(2img) {
          $(2img).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
      });
}
</script>
<body>
<table width="1659" height="701" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
<th width="325" scope="col"><div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;"><img                         id="img1" src="" width="232" height="232" alt="" onmouseover="showimg(2img1)" onmouseout="hideimg(2img1)" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
<img id="2img1" src="" width="32" height="32" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 150px; visibility:hidden;"/></div></th>

<th width="325" scope="col"><div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;"><img id="img2" src="" width="232" height="232" alt="" onmouseover="showimg(2img2)" onmouseout="hideimg(2img2)" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
<img id="2img2" src="" width="32" height="32" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 150px; visibility:hidden;"/></div></th>

<th width="325" scope="col"><div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;"><img id="img3" src="" width="232" height="232" alt="" onmouseover="showimg(2img3)" onmouseout="hideimg(2img3)" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
<img id="2img3" src="" width="32" height="32" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 150px; visibility:hidden;"/></div></th>

<th width="325" scope="col"><div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;"><img id="img4" src="" width="232" height="232" alt="" onmouseover="showimg(2img4)" onmouseout="hideimg(2img4)" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
<img id="2img4" src="" width="32" height="32" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 150px; visibility:hidden;"/></div></th>

<th width="325" scope="col"><div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;"><img id="img5" src="" width="232" height="232" alt="" onmouseover="showimg(2img5)" onmouseout="hideimg(2img5)" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
<img id="2img5" src="" width="32" height="32" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 150px; visibility:hidden;"/></div></th>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd find it better to do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('table > div > img:first').hover(function() {
        showImg($(this).next());
    }, function() {
        hideImg($(this).next());
    });
});
```

This way you wont be replicating the onmouseover and onmouseoout code in your html.

The errors in your code are - No # for the id of the images to fade, although it seems to work in chrome I don't know if it will work as expected in every browser, also the function names don't have the same case.

Answer (score 1):

`$(2img)` should be  `$('#2img')` and that's it

Answer (score 1):

$(2img) should be $('#'+2img) and invoke the function like showImg("2img2")

Answer (score 0):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/H2csn/)

```
$('.tb td').each(function(){
    $(this).find('img').wrapAll('<div />');
    $('.tb td div').css({position:'relative'});   
    $(this).find('img:eq(1)').css({position:'absolute', left:'0px', top:'0px'}).hide();   
});

$('.tb td div').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('img:eq(1)').stop().fadeTo(400,1);
},function(){
    $(this).find('img:eq(1)').stop().fadeTo(400,0);
});
```